# Find the chromatic polynomials to the wheel graph W6

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am starting with graph theory and have this exercise of wheel graphs, but I do not really understand how to do it.

Could anyone explain me how to find the chromatic polynomial of this graph? The book suggests using deletion/addition-contraction but I do not understand.

This is the wheel graph:

[W6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXRs7.png)

Comment: Dp you know the chromatic polynomial of the cycle graph $C_5$? If we call that $f(x)$ then the chromatic polynomial of $W_6$ (the wheel graph with $6$ vertices) is $xf(x-1)$. Because, if you have $x$ colors available, then there are $x$ ways to color the central vertex, and after you've done that, there are $f(x-1)$ ways to color the rest of the vertices with the other $x-1$ colors.

Answer (score 1):

**The method of deletion/contraction**

The idea of this method of counting colourings is as follows.

Delete an edge, joining vertices $u$ and $v$ say, of a simple graph. When you count the colourings $D$ of this simpler graph you will overcount because you will include colourings where $u$ and $v$ have been given the same colour.

These unwanted colourings are precisely the number of colourings $C$ where  $u$ and $v$ are forced to have the same colouring by contracting edge $uv$ so that  $u$ and $v$ become the same vertex.

So there are $D-C$ colourings of the original graph.

**Example: For the cycle graphs $C_n$**

If you delete an edge of $C_n$ then, using $k$ colours, the simpler graph can be coloured in $k(k-1)^{n-1}$ ways since you can colour an end vertex in $k$ ways and then colour each successive vertex in $k-1$ ways.

We must now subtract the number of colourings when the edge is contracted. In which case the graph is $C_{n-1}$.

Now the chromatic polynomial for $C_3$ is clearly $k(k-1)(k-2)$.

So the chromatic polynomial for $C_4$ is $k(k-1)^3-k(k-1)(k-2)=k(k-1)(k^2-3k+3)$.

The chromatic polynomial for $C_5$ is $k(k-1)^4-k(k-1)(k^2-3k+3)=k(k-1)(k^3-4k^2+6k-4)$.

You can probably see the pattern now but you only require $C_5$ for your problem.

**Your problem: W_6**

Use the method suggested by @bof together with the result for $C_5$.